# TensorFlow - inference to only a subset of the model

Tags: tensor, tensorflow-serving

Is there a way to inference TF model with "filter"? 
Imagine my training data points can be clustered and be labeled (just an example, it's not vision ML)

1. datapoint1-> cat   (parent label animals)
2. datapoint2-> dog   (parent label animals)
3. datapoint3-> mazda (parent label cars)
4. datapoint4-> toyota (parent label cars)

Let's say I train this in TensorFlow.
Assuming that when inferencing the model, the consumer "knows" the parent label - is it possible to narrow the "search" and inference time?
For example - assuming the client knows data point is a car, and only wished to identify which cat is it - can I "filter" the TF classification process?

Comment: Tensorflow is not a recognition model, it is a framework to write a recognition model in. I'm sure it is possible, but what exactly do you hope to get as an answer here? Code? A link to a paper? What model do you train? This question is quite unspecific.

Comment: I'm a newbie - couldn't find this feature (or maybe I didn't look for it right) - I hope to get a better understanding if this is possible to achieve in one model, multiple models etc. as this is a business requirement (work only on the right category on inference time, and get the sorted confidence only for that cateogry) - btw it's a (text) intent classification

Comment: First of all, I assume you are talking about neural networks here? Neural networks don't think in categories. They just directly match things. First of all, you actually need a model that does some matching. Currently the best performing ones are VGG and Resnet. Maybe reading about those is a good direction to continue your search.

Comment: Well, you could always train one model for every category, then you could only use that specific model in inference time. But that would create a lot of models. Also, if you need intent classification, you will probably stumble across RNN's instead of VGG and Resnet, which are both image recognizers. This is a non-trivial topic and it takes a lot of background knowledge to understand it.